# JavaFX - Creating non-selectable item in ListView

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using `JFXListView` and `JFXListCell` from the library called [jfoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/) and the purpose and function are same as the regular `ListView`.

The list contains some `Label`, `Button` and `AnchorPane`. At the very top and bottom of the list, I want to add non-selectable item. The item `should not be selectable on mouse click`, `should not be able to focus` and `should not be able to scroll`.

I though of using `updateItem()` function and setting the item disable:

```
@FXML
JFXListView listView;
ObservableList<AnchorPane> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private void initializeListView(){

    AnchorPane headerBottomPane = new AnchorPane();
    headerBottomPane.setId("headerBottomPane");
    ....//some property of AnchorPane
    list.add(headerBottomPane); //Add header AnchorPane

    while(true){
        AnchorPane listContainer = new AnchorPane();
        Label title = new Label();
        Label subtitle = new Label();
        Button button = new Button();
        Button button2 = new Button();
        //Some code here...

        listContainer.getChildren().addAll(label, subtitle, button, button2);

        list.add(listContainer);
        //some code here...
    }

    list.add(headerBottomPane); //Add bottom AnchorPane

    listView.setCellFactory(new CallBack<JFXListView, JFXListCell>(){
        @Override
        public JFXListCell call(JFXListView param){
            return new JFXListCell<AnchorPane>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(AnchorPane anchorPane, boolean empty){
                    super.updateItem(anchorPane, empty);
                    if(anchorPane != null){
                        if(anchorPane.getId.equals("headerBottomPane")){
                            setDisable(true);
                        }
                        setItem(anchorPane);
                    }else{
                        setItem(null);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

I am able to disable the top and last item of the list, the item is no longer able to select using `mouseClick`.

But the problem is, it is focusable when I use the `Keyboard arrow up` and `arrow down` another strange thing is when I use the `mouse wheel` to scroll the list, some of the item are becoming non-selectable too.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `SelectionModel` and the `FocusModel` (if the `JFXListVies` makes use of those of course, I am not familar with jfoenix)

Comment: why do you add controls to the list? that's wrong nearly always: list items should be data objects, which are visualized by controls (re-usable in a listCell)

Comment: @kleopatra - I think it shouldn't matter, list can have Nodes too.

Comment: @Polar they certainly _can_ but about 99% when anybody does add controls to a list she's trying to solve the real problem by wrong means ;) That is trying to help with the controls doesn't help with the real problem

Comment: @kleopatra - I see... Thanks for that knowledge, I didn't know about it. LOL :)

Comment: @kleopatra - say, I want to create list with lots of control, then what is the best way to do it if its not ListView?

Comment: @Polar why? what would you want to achieve? Don't invent fake requirements, there's enough to do with the real stuff <g>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put your `listView.setCellFactory()` function at the top of the code where you adding those items, try to initialize it before you add the item.

and inside your `updateItem()` try to use `setMouseTransparent()` and `setFocusTravesable()`.

```
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(AnchorPane anchorPane, boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(anchorPane, empty);
                if(anchorPane != null){
                    if(anchorPane.getId.equals("headerBottomPane")){
                        setItem(anchorPane); //moved at the top
                        setMouseTransparent(true); //added this line
                        setFocusTraversable(false); //added this line
                        setDisable(true);
                }else{
                    setItem(null);
                }
            }
```

I haven't test it but I hope it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of just using a VBox, and putting your top unselectable item first, then the ListView with all the selectable items, then the bottom unselectable item...